# Chrome: Showing new window on top without giving it focus

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7-x64

I'd like to open up a new chrome window (not tab) and have it take focus in its address bar immediately.

It works when pressing CTRL+N to open the new window (presumably from the current process) but not when clicking the Icon in the quick launch bar or on the desktop (thus launching a new process).
Then it just opens up, comes to the front, cursor blinking in the adress bar, but it does *not* have focus there. Typing sends the input to desktop I believe since no open program seems to have the focus then. This is particularly annoying when I was working with a different program and want to have a new browser window.

My Chrome version is 23.0.1271.97 on Windows 7 x64, and as far as I remember it worked fine until version 17.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just published a small Chrome Extension which aims at solving this bug! So far it worked great for me (on Window 7 64-bit).
You can find it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-new-window-focus/opmhcfhkhiodgapmnaolhmekmfihmecp

Let me know if you encounter any issues!

Cheers,
Yuvi

Comment: This extension is no longer available, and I'm still having same issue on Windows 10. Also getting the warning "This extension violates the Chrome Web Store policy." where I have this extension enabled. I don't suppose you have an update for it?